# Stuck in the shell prompt in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, vmware-workstation

I have just installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 on VMWare Workstation and when I open it there is a shell prompt asking for username and password. After that it just says

> jkell311@ubuntu:`$

I want to get to the GUI and start using ubuntu server. I know this sounds like a stupid question but I have had no experience with linux nor ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo service lightdm start` or `startx` works?

Comment: it says "lightdm: unrecognised service

Comment: The server version does not come with a display manager by default. The assumption is that you need all the processing power of your system for services (web, database, email, etc). You can install a display manager on top, but it kind of beats the purpose of using the server edition. Perhaps you should consider installing the desktop edition instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Server edition of Ubuntu does not come with a GUI by default. You can either use the Desktop edition, or you can install a desktop package manually. Just log in with your user name at the prompt you see and then run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

That will bring all the files and packages necessary to run a GUI on the server. Before you do this, I suggest you read this Wiki page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI to decide whether it's worth it for you.

Comment: that is the code i used but after it was installed I typed startx and It took me to a white screen

Comment: @jaydz49 don't use `startx`. Either run `sudo service lightdm start` or just reboot the machine.

Comment: it turns out the code you said wasn't the same code, I am downloading package now :)

Comment: @tardon how big is this package? because it is taking a long time!!!

Comment: @jaydz49 that will bring in _loads_ of packages, the GUI is a heavy thing. As Sylvain pointed out below, the Ubuntu Server is not expected to work with a GUI so installing it requires installing a lot of dependencies. Unless you're sure you want the server edition, I would just reinstall with the Desktop edition. It will take about as much time and will probably be simpler all around.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal as Ubuntu server does not provide a GUI. Most of the time server installations run in headless mode.

If you need the full Ubuntu Desktop (the GUI started by `lightdm`) then you have to reinstall your system with one the desktop [iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: Surely the reinstall is not needed! Why not just install the package?

Comment: Both solution are possible, as it's a fresh installation tough, I'd reinstall so that I don't have any server packages on the system.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that the OP _wanted_ server packages but also a GUI.